# Is there a way to set XML::Twig's preferences to pretty print using tabs instead of spaces?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I've made a perl script that modifies an XML file.  But the resulting file now has spaces instead of tabs for indenting.  I've looked around, and I can't seem to find a setting to switch it to tabs.  I know I could do a search and replace on it, but that's an extra step for something that should be very common, so I was wondering if I missed something.

Comment: `XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint` and `XML::Tidy` allow you to specify an indent string, but it is fixed for `XML::Twig`. It would be a simple matter to write a post-processing phase that converts multiple leading spaces to tab characters. But why do you want tabs there anyway? The usual eight-space indent that they provide is huge, and would render the XML much less readable.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs

```
...
my $state = $twig->global_state;
$state->{indent} = "\t";
$twig->set_global_state( $state );
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than editing the global state there's [a set_indent() method](https://github.com/mirod/xmltwig/blob/5f46757bfc38d951ebf3fa5d5fa0637a9c015f5d/Twig.pm#L8053):

```perl
$twig->set_indent("\t");
```